# MVC Query Result no accept null values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwLf6.png)    Function ListarTipoMascotas() As JsonResult
Dim db As New LQTestDataContext
Dim Listado = From tipomascota In db.TipoMascotas
Where tipomascota.BHABILITADO = 1
Select New With {
.Id = tipomascota.IIDTIPOMASCOTA,
.Nombre = tipomascota.NOMBRE
}

```
        Return New JsonResult With {.Data = Listado,
            .JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            }

    End Function
```

This is my function in VB. MVC , is work fine, but when I have null values the LINQ sent a error.
I'm working with LINQ for my conexion database,
My question is, how I can to do, to this result I can return null values without any problem.
Thank you. I read you.

Comment: You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. If an exception is thrown, specify where and what the error message was.

Comment: sorry for misunderstood , I attached some picture to show the error.  I'm working with ASP.NET WIT VB. in my controller I use the linQ to Database conexion but when I do the function in my controller sometimes ,  I can't see the data because my metadata there is a null value, My question is How I can to avoid the LINQ have this behavior and my controller can to ignore the null values in the LINQ conexion .

Comment: Message from browser : [InvalidOperationException: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.DateTime which is a non-nullable value type.] Read_VB$AnonymousType_2`11(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +5153 ystem.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +72 System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat,